# hwo to declear a object with one value assignment to it self in typescript

Tags: typescript

when i declear an object and add a key which assign to it self, i tried some, but always an error hear.

```js
 const a = {
  d:123,
  a:a//<-TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'a' used before its declaration.
}

const a = {d:123}
a.a=a;//<-TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ d: number; }'.

    const a: { d: number, a: typeof a } = {//<-TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'a' used before its declaration.
        d: 123
    }
    a.a = a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples 1. and 3. do not work since you're trying to reference the variable `a` which is just being assigned a value in the very same expression. Since it is not defined at that time you can not reference it in the expression itself.

With your 2. example: when not provided with an explicit type TypeScript tries to infer the type of a variable when it is declared. I.e. after the declaration of

```
const a = {d:123}
```

`a` has a type of `{d: number}`. This type has no property `a.a` so trying to assign to it will fail as shown.

To be able to assign `a` to a property of itself `a` must be of a type that does allow for this. You can achieve this by either explicitly declaring with a respective type or by just using the `any` type if it is not important to you:

```
// using "any" type 
const a: any = {d:123};
a.a = a;

// using a type alias with optional properties
type A = {
  d: number;
  a?: A;
}

const a: A = {d: 123};
a.a = a;

// using a type alias with an optional value
type A = {
  d: number;
  a: A | null;
}

const a: A = {
  d: 123,
  a: null,
};
a.a = a;
```

[Click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFcGcEsDsHNQCICGsCeTQBd0AcBTUAKAGMB7WSbUFALlo1AF5QBvAEzoEYAmAZgC+AbmIoAdCha1RxEBBgJaOfERQAbaCkigA7tGwALUOTzZolDaDwAnUwRvmCkYrkKgAQtLbFQoLqCw4AC2AEYOon6hAPwMHqKCxGSU1KChcd4BfEKioeKh0qGy8lBwiFJuapraegbGaCZmFrBWAG4a4ASuqqAAwt6+-gxBYRGDpAz9AD6B4OrqCUkUVDQTfQN+WQIANOPDc+q7ImTipNKkwkA) to try it out live.

Note the difference between 2. and 3. approach:

- with the 2.: `a` of type `A` may or may not have a property `a.a`. But *if* it does the value *must* be of type `A` itself
- with the 3.: `a` of type `A` *must* have a property `a.a` but its value may be `null` or itself of type `A`

Also note that with all of these solutions the type system will only check that `a` and `a.a` have the *same type* but will **not** guarantee that `a` and `a.a` refer to the *same object*!